# Spring-boot oAuth2 with bitbucket

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I need to add Spring boot oAuth2 bitbucket authentication. I am not getting any tutorial or blog for spring boot application.yml configuration for bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: You need to create an OAuth consumer on Bitbucket

Sadly, seem it seem only available on the premium account

https://vssue.js.org/guide/bitbucket.html#create-a-new-oauth-consumer

**Step 2**: I believe all OAuth third parties work the same way.

You can looking for "Login with Github Springboot example" and just replace the info

Here is my .yaml file for login with Github.

[image]

Cause the Bitbucket Oauth is not free, so I can't try it

**[UPDATE]** Bitbucket OAuth document

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/